# How do I get results of a MySQL JOIN where records meet a value criteria in joined table?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

This may be simple but I can't figure it out...

I have two tables:

tbl_results:

```
runID | balance |
1     | 3432
2     | 5348
3     | 384
```

tbl_phases:

```
runID_fk | pc |
1        | 34 
1        | 2
1        | 18
2        | 15
2        | 18
2        | 20
3        | -20
3        | 10
3        | 60
```

I want to get a recordset of: **runID, balance, min(pc), max(pc)** only **where pc>10 and pc<50** for each runID as a group, excluding runIDs where any associated pc value is outside of value range.

I would want the following results from what's described above:

```
runID | balance | min_pc | max_pc
2     | 5348    | 15     | 20
```

... because runID=1&3 have pc values that fall outside the numeric range for pc noted above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need min(pc) > 10 AND max(pc) < 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply filters based on your requirements in your having clause. You may try the following.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    r.runID,
    MAX(r.balance) as balance,
    MIN(p.pc) as min_pc,
    MAX(p.pc) as max_pc
FROM
    tbl_results r
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_phases p ON p.runID_fk = r.runID
GROUP BY 
    r.runID
HAVING
    MIN(p.pc)>10 AND MAX(p.pc) < 50;
```

| runID | balance | min_pc | max_pc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5348 | 15 | 20 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    r.runID,
    MAX(r.balance) as balance,
    MIN(p.pc) as min_pc,
    MAX(p.pc) as max_pc
FROM
    tbl_results r
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_phases p ON p.runID_fk = r.runID
GROUP BY 
    r.runID
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.pc <= 10 or p.pc >= 50 THEN 1  END) =0;
```

| runID | balance | min_pc | max_pc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5348 | 15 | 20 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vc2Mnd2sP7tgZCtPtV47YU/1)

*Updated with comments from Rahul Biswas*